Is there a simple proof for this integral trick?
I recently learned that a integral of type $\int \frac {p x + q}{a x^{2}+ b x + c} \text {d} x$ can be written as
$$px + q = A \cdot \frac{\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \left(a x^{2} + b x + c \right) + B$$
Then the integral can be simplified to
$$A \int \frac {2 a x + b}{a x^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x + B \int \frac {1}{a x^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x$$
What is the proof for this?

The statement in the textbook:


This is just carefully splitting up the numerator of the integrand such that one group of terms matches the derivative of the denominator.

For all $a \neq 0$,
$$
p x + q = \frac {p}{2 a} \cdot \left( 2 a x + b \right) - \Big(\frac {b p}{2 a} - q \Big).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int \frac {p x + q}{a {x}^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x = \frac {p}{2 a} \int \frac {2 a x + b}{a {x}^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x - \Big(\frac {b p}{2 a} - q \Big) \int \frac {1}{a {x}^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x.
$$
Does this help?

The proof is simply to set $A=\frac{p}{2a}$ and $B = q-\frac{bp}{2a}$

I assume that $p, a \neq 0$, since otherwise we are in a much simpler regime.
We first observe:
$$
\frac{\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \left(a x^{2} + b x + c \right)
=
2a x + b
$$
We first fix the coefficient of the linear term. We want $A$ such that
$$
p = A \cdot 2a
$$
Hence
$$
A = \frac{p}{2a}
$$
Notice that this requires $a \neq 0$.
Now,
$$
A ( 2a x + b ) = p x + Ab,
$$
and we pick $B$ such that
$$
Ab + B = q,
$$
which means $B = q - Ab$.
With that, we indeed have
$$
\int \frac{px+q}{a x^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x
=
A \int \frac {2 a x + b}{a x^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x + B \int \frac {1}{a x^{2} + b x + c} \text {d} x$$

The statement is part of a more general result, or rather "trick" to use the same parlance, that allows you to write the quotient of two polynomials $\Large\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where $deg(q(x))\gt deg(p(x))$ as the sum of simple fractions of the form $\Large\frac{A}{(ax+b)^n}$ and $\Large\frac{B}{(x^2+bx+c)^m}$ where $b^2-4c\lt0$ and $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.
The fact that every polynomial can be written as the product of linear and quadratic factors follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.
This wikipedia entry on Partial Fraction Decomposition and the accepted answer on this mathstack post will help.
